# Representation of a group with dimension equal to a number of conjugacy classes

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

My question is the following: is there a (call it "canonical", "standard", or some other interesting and known) representation (probably reducible) of a finite group, which dimension is equal to a number of conjugacy classes of the group? It can be complex, and can even be projective. My main interest is the case of a symmetric group.

I am not interested in trivial cases like a direct sum of many trivial representations, for example.

Comment: I think this is very unlikely. For instance $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has $(p+5)/2$ conjugacy classes and its irreducible complex characters have dimensions $1$, $(p\pm 1)/2$ (twice, sign depending on $p$ modulo $4$), $p-1$, $p$, $p+1$. So at least $2$ copies of the trivial character are needed.

Comment: A more natural question is a representation whose dimension is $k(G)\cdot |G|$, where $k(G)$ is the number of conjugacy classes. Such a representation has character $\psi(w)=\#\{(u,v)\in G\times G\,:\, w=uvu^{-1}v^{-1}\}$. Moreover, the multiplicity of an irreducible character $\chi$ is $|G|/\dim(\chi)$ (a positive integer). It is an open problem to find a "natural" action of $G$ that affords this representation. This would provide a new proof that $\dim(\chi)$ divides $|G|$.

Comment: And for the monster group, the smallest degree of a nontrivial representation is *way* bigger than the number of conjugacy classes.

Comment: What would be the purpose or interest of such a representation? \\ @RichardStanley, I am confused by "[Such a representation has character …](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434919/representation-of-a-group-with-dimension-equal-to-a-number-of-conjugacy-classes#comment1120356_434919)".  Surely this character formula does not follow just from the dimension?  Do you mean rather that one looks for a representation with that character, whose dimension is then necessarily $k(G)\cdot\lvert G\rvert$?

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody who gave an answer. In fact what I ment to ask was if there was a way to "naturally" define a representation with dimention equal to a number of conjugacy classes for every symmetric group. So the monster group is not a case of this consideration. Trivial representations may appear in a decomposition to irreps. I am asking for some "natural", meaningful representation possessing some properties, or interesting realizations

Comment: The log of the number of partitions of $n$ is asymptotically $2\sqrt{\pi^2/6} \sqrt{n} + a \log n$, whereas by Stirling's formula, log of the mean degree of an irreducible character is asymptotically $n \log n - n + c \log n$, for some constants $a, c$. So almost all irreducible characters do not have small enough degree to contribute to the proposed character.

Comment: @LSpice: I should have said "An example of such a representation ..."